# Shiny: Expand right hand sidebar by clicking on the datatable

Tags: r, shiny

I have created a shiny app that looks something like this:

```
## Library
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboardPlus)
library(shinyjs)
library(DT)

data <- cbind(
  seq(from = 1, to = 30, by = 1),
  sample(seq(from = 100, to = 300, by = 10), size = 30, replace = TRUE),
  sample(seq(from = 1, to = 100, by = 9), size = 30, replace = TRUE),
  sample(seq(from = 50, to = 60, by = 2), size = 30, replace = TRUE),
  sample(seq(from = 100, to = 130, by = 1), size = 30, replace = TRUE)
) %>% 
  as.data.frame()

names(data) <- c("Colimn 1", "Colimn 2", "Colimn 3", "Colimn 4", "Colimn 5")

## UI
ui <- dashboardPagePlus(
  dashboardHeaderPlus(
    enable_rightsidebar = TRUE,
    rightSidebarIcon = "angle-left"
  ),
  dashboardSidebar(),
  dashboardBody(dataTableOutput("dataTable")),
  rightSidebar()
)

## Server
server <- function(input, output) { 
  output$dataTable <- renderDataTable({
    datatable(data,
    rownames= FALSE,
    selection = "single",
    escape = FALSE,
    ## Get the name of the row on click
    callback = JS("table.on('click.dt', 'tr',
                  function() {
                  Shiny.onInputChange('rows', table.rows(this).data().toArray());
                  });")
    )
  })

  observeEvent(!is.null(input$rows),
               {
              ????
               })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

What I would like to have is when user clicks on the data table row, the right-hand sidebar expands with more detailed information about that row there.

Once the user clicks on any row of data table, the sidebar should open, if the user clicks on any other row it should stay open. It should only collapse when the button on top (that is already there) is pressed to collapse it.

I tried to play around `shinyjs::removeClass` however i did not manage to make it work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `library(shinyjs)` add `shinyjs::useShinyjs()` to the dashboard body, and in the server function add:

```
selected_row <- reactive({
    if(!is.null(input$rows)){
      shinyjs::addClass(selector = "aside.control-sidebar", class = "control-sidebar-open")
      data %>% filter(`Colimn 1`== input$rows[1])
    }
  })
```